Testing Puzzles for Feedback: Enigmatic Puzzles 3
I'm starting to test out puzzles for my second puzzle book (link to the first). They're all enigmatic word puzzles. Try out this new puzzle I'm testing and share any feedback you might have to make it even better. Happy to share hints if you ask:

The answers to the clues are:

 Caught in the act    RED-HANDED
 Closed pore  WHITEHEAD
 Suck up  BROWNNOSE
 How you get strength in Blue GOLD TEETH (Pokemon reference)
 Coal miner's disease BLACK LUNG
 ---
 Charles Hampton Indigo   CRIMSON CHIN
 Late flight  RED EYE
 Manual laborers  BLUE COLLAR
 Wounded decoration   PURPLE HEART
 Coward   YELLOW-BELLY
 Fairy tale murderer of his six wives BLUEBEARD
 Werewolf surname GREYBACK (from Harry Potter)
 Wireless technology  BLUETOOTH
 Kaiba's ace monster  BLUE EYES (white dragon)
 Siksikaisitapi   BLACKFOOT
 Expert gardener  GREEN THUMB

To use these,

 we can match each color with the palette, and index into the answers of that color by position on the palette. So CRIMSON is in the first position, which means we take the first letter of its answer; WHITE is on the third, which means we take the third letter of its; RED and YELLOW are on the fourth...

 (Of course, CRIMSON/RED and YELLOW/GOLD must be disambiguated through context, using the results.)

 Doing this gives the phrase HINDU CELEBRATION - which clues HOLI, a very thematic holiday!


Would love to hear your thoughts on disambiguation (or if it's ok to have to work backwards there) and also on Kaiba's ace monster (which is a little trickier than the others during the extraction step). Either way, great solve!


 Caught in the act: RED handed
 Closed pore: WHITE head
 Suck up: BROWN nose
 How you get strength in Blue: ??
 Coal miner's disease: BLACK lung


 Charles Hampton Indigo: CRIMSON chin
 Late flight: RED eye
 Manual labourers: BLUE collar
 Wounded decoration: PURPLE heart
 Coward: YELLOW
 Fairy tale murderer of his six wives: BLUEbeard
 Werewolf surname: GREY
 Wireless technology: BLUEtooth
 Kaiba's ace monster: BLUE eyes WHITE dragon
 Siksikaitsitapi: BLACKfoot
 Expert gardener: GREEN fingers

Is there more being sought than this list of answers?

Pretty good start here for sure! The next step would be for you to think about the idea of extraction (taking a letter from each answer to find an ultimate answer).
